# Title top of modal div css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, materialize

[image: I want a title for modal widow to appear like this]

I want a title for modal widow to appear like this, 
ie; above the modal widow on top of overlay.

```
.modal-content .modal_heading{
            position: absolute;
            top:-4rem;
            z-index: 999999;
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            }
```

But its not working

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].